# Should ibatis domain class be used as javabean?

Tags: java, database

I have a table category mapped to domain class Category using iBatis. Should I use this class as a JavaBean? The bean for product should have other attributes such as number of products in this category. These attributes are not part of the domain class Category. If i use Category as bean class, is it still relevant? Is it better to provide a wrapper class like CategoryBean in this case? Will it increase the complexity of the code?

Answer (score 1):

There are several sides to this debate (and it is a debate).

Firstly, there is a pervasive view in Java software development circles that software needs to be highly layered. This often means pulling out domain objects and translating them to presentation objects. It can go even further and have service objects and others in between.

This often ends up being a whole lot of boilerplate property copying for questionable benefit.

One question to ask yourself is this: are the objects coming out of Ibatis fit for presentation? Or are they generic in the sense that you, for example, have one class per table?

A lightweight Java application is well within it's rights to choose an approach whereby the Ibatis will run queries that will return the exact information the view layer needs and then pass it all the way up (which won't be far). Now this has scalability issues on large applications. You could end up with hundreds or even thousands of these things so in those situations you might need a different approach. Then again, in those situations you'll probably just end up with thousands of presentation objects instead. Robbing Peter to pay Paul?

I personally disfavour the one-class-per-table approach in Ibatis. That's not it's strength. That's Hibernate's and JPA's strength. Ibatis's strength is that it can easily pull out anything as well as any SQL query can (because it is just SQL). Use it that way unless it creates problems for you.